# Mutable data section?

Tags: assembly, mutable, instruction-set

I'm developing a virtual CPU for fun and I am currently working on the assembly part.

Now I wonder if values in the `.data` section should be mutable or not.

```
section .data
  MyGlobalVar dw 10h
```

In the places where I reference *MyGlobalVar*, should I resolve the value at assembly time or runtime? Which would be the most appropriate way of doing it?

```
mov ra, 10h          ; Assembly time resolved value
mov ra, [0x00000000] ; Address of MyGlobalVar dereferenced when executed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implicitly dereferenced at assemble time to produce an immediate constant, you'd always get the value from the source code.  That's what `equ` is for; programmers can use that if that's what they want instead of a load from `.rodata`.  (In that case, the bytes in that section would only be accessed by code that indexes a lookup table or something like that.)

And obviously that doesn't work at all for mutable data, it has to be a load from the memory location other code might have modified.

**It's assembly language; don't change the program instructions to something with an architecturally different effect.**  You're writing an assembler, not a compiler.  Even a section like `.rodata` that normally gets mapped into read-only pages can get modified by a debugger, potentially.